# Как работать со сканером в java?

Tags: java

Вот допустим я создал сканер чтобы счесть вводимые данные. Как мне их использовать в конструкция if, switch, for и т. д.. Покажите пожалуйста синтаксис на примерах.

Comment: что именно показать?.. как переменные можно использовать в конструкциях?

Comment: Вам интерпретатор написать? Или просто краткий экскурс в синтаксис Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Класс [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) используется для получения данных введенных пользователем в виде `String`, `byte`, `short`, `int`, `long`, `float`, `double`. Пользуются им примерно так:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = scanner.nextInt();
String s = scanner.next();
```

Затем эти переменные можно использовать в любых конструкциях языка.

```
if (i > 0) {
    i = i + 1
} // вы же это спросили?
```

Comment: Да, спасибо большое.

Comment: @pimanov_andrey если ответ вам помог, [отметьте его решением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).